# Accessing the data from a $.post in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url('channel_partners/get_cp_text'); ?>', {cp_lang: language},
       function(data) {
        alert('icon: ' + data.cp_icon);
        }
    );
```

The URL is CodeIgniter.  Don't be distracted by that.  It returns the proper data, too.  If I alert data I get the proper JSON-encoded array back.  It looks like this.

```
{"cp_icon":"test1","authorized_cp":"test2"}
```

So I how do alert "test1" if not by data.cp_icon?  If I use data.cp_icon, I get an undefined result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url('channel_partners/get_cp_text'); ?>', {cp_lang: language},
   function(data) {
        alert('icon: ' + data.cp_icon);
    }, "json"
);
```

Adding the data type will tell it to parse it as JSON and not as just a string (which is what is happening).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using jquery $.ajax and specifying the dataType as json...

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo site_url('channel_partners/get_cp_text'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {cp_lang: language},
    success: function(data){
        alert('icon: ' + data.cp_icon);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {cp_lang: language},
    success: function(data){
        alert('icon: ' + data.cp_icon);
    }
});